# Registered model visible in the MLflow UI, but not in the REST API

Tags: python, sqlite, mlflow

I am using MLflow. I have done some experiments which are showing in the MLflow UI and am able to see those experiments in the [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) API also.

But when I registered the model using code and MLflow UI, both models displayed on MLflow, but when I called the REST API, it showed it was not present. If my API is wrong, then it should not give me experiment data, but it is giving me experiment data, but not the registered model.

I also created a tracking URI on [Mac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macintosh). Please find the below import of MLflow:

```
import mlflow

mlflow.set_tracking_uri("http://localhost:5000")


# Set the experiment
mlflow.set_experiment("exp_2")

# Start MLflow
with mlflow.start_run():
    # Check if metrics present in this run_metrics if yes log that
    for metric in run_metrics:
            mlflow.log_metric(metric, run_metrics[metric])


    # We use artifact when we are saving files
    mlflow.log_artifact('confusion_matrix.png', 'confusion_materix')

    # This below code we use for tag
    mlflow.set_tag("tag1", "KNN Algo")
    mlflow.set_tags({"tag2":"Testing", "tag3":"Testing2"})

    # Send the model also
    #mlflow.sklearn.log_model(knn, "model",registered_model_name='Register_first_Model_1')
    mlflow.sklearn.log_model(knn, "model")

print('It is logged to Experiment - %s' %( experiment_name))
```

Here it shows a model in the UI:

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVta5.png)

But when I call the API, it says not present:

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUD58.png)

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoaG8.png)

I tried hacking the tracking URI. It is all good, but still I am not able to see that. My main purpose is to serve this model, but when I go to serve it, it the says model is not present.

Comment: Please post as a text  and error  not screenshot,

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76288952/edit). Thanks in advance.